# script that checks and compares table structures from different databases and sends alarm if different

Tags: mysql

Just wanted to ask, i want to create a script that will check table structures from 2 databases ( they must be the same).
If different send an email alert.

I have the option of doing a mysqldump and doing a diff , but the databases are very huge.
I've read about maatkit, and other tools but i'm not too sure how to proceed .
Anyone who can give direction and the best tool.

Comment: You might want to also include your process which requires two different databases to be identical, at least at certain times.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [mysqldbcompare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldbcompare.html) from the MySQL Utilities. It's an official part of the MySQL product line. You can diff structure or data or both. Read the documentation for details about these options.

You mention Maatkit, but that toolkit was replaced years ago by Percona Toolkit (same people working on it and same code, just changed name). Since then, the MySQL Utilities have duplicated some of the tools in Percona Toolkit.